# Sync big data from droplet to Digital Ocean Space (S3)

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, rsync, s3fs

My web project static folder's size is around 10 GB and it is stored in Digital Ocean Droplet. Today I tried out Digital Ocean Space and idea was to copy and sync all my storage files to the new space.

My first approach started from mounting folder.

I created `.passwd-s3fs` file at home directory and added text `space_name:space_key:space_secret`

Then I installed s3fs package by command:

```
apt-get install s3fs
```

Created new storage folder in `var` for mounting:

```
s3fs space_name /var/storage -ourl=https://ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

At the end using rsync I started to sync files to my space

```
rsync -av --stats --progress /var/www/project/static/* /var/storage
```

Well, syncing was started, but it was pretty slow.

For example, how pdf file was synced:

```
static/demo.pdf
        812,707 100%  194.60kB/s    0:00:03 (xfr#1, ir-chk=3084/3086)
```

Firstly files inside static folder were synced.
But 30 minutes has passed, folders are still empty in DO space. There is not any error in shell.

Maybe there is another sensible way to migrate my static files of Droplet to Space?

Comment: Can you please clarify how you need it to be accessed if at all? This makes the difference between treat it S3/Spaces as object storage, vs layer a POSIX-like filesystem on top of S3/Spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pending the clarification comment I left, I'll explain both options. DigitalOcean Spaces uses [Ceph RGW](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/luminous/radosgw/) as the S3 implementation, but the answers here apply to both DigitalOcean Spaces and AWS S3.

Disclaimer: I work on DigitalOcean Spaces specifically, because it's a deployment of Ceph.

**filesystem-on-top-of-S3**

This is what you're doing right now, there's a variety of options, like `s3fs`. The [s3fs limitations](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse#limitations) page goes into some of the concerns with filesystem-on-top-of-S3.

The primary upside here is you get it get exposed in your filesystem and can mostly plug it into applications directly, without modifying the applications. This can break depending on consistency and POSIX, as well as be slow as it's limited by latency to S3 now, with lots of round trips.

The major downside is you frequently need the same original tool to access the content again, as a filesystem, and it's not always directly available like you copied the content onto a webserver.

**Native S3**

If you don't need programs to transparently open S3 content like it's in the local filesystem, a better option is to use S3 in a native method. Upload your content with `s3cmd` or `rclone` (pretty fast), and treat it more like a web-server of static content than a local filesystem. Don't set your content as public unless you really want it to be public, and you can consider using SSE-C to encrypt the data if you don't want it unencrypted after it leaves your immediate control.

The other major tip is that you should try minimize your latency from the droplet to the Spaces endpoint. Pick the Spaces closest to your droplet.

Comment: is SSL a must? (i.e. I do not care when doing it from the droplet) when trying `s3cmd --no-ssl` I am getting `ERROR: S3 error: 302 (Found)` all the time

Comment: @ciekawy Yes SSL is required, DigitalOcean best practices are aligned with SSL Everywhere.